# With pixel scroll precision enabled in Emacs 29.1 RC1, is the following code still required?

Tags: scrolling, mouse

I have the following code in my Emacs configuration to enhance the default scrolling behavior:

```
(use-package mwheel
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1)))
  (mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
  (mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't)
  :config
  (setq scroll-step 1)
  (setq scroll-conservatively 1000))
```

However, I've noticed that Emacs 29.1 RC1 now comes with `pixel-scroll-precision-mode.` If I have pixel precision scroll mode enabled, is the code above still necessary?